# URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs); Attribute android:versionCode is not allowed here

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISmXX.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI3ns.png)
```

https://github.com/js42721/sharkbait
`My other projects do not have this error, although they are quite similar, so what is the error? Can someone help me? You can use the project link to test it, then send the project back after you have fixed it for me help me run this project`